# Is an internet connection required to install a GUI like KDE?

Tags: linux, internet

Is an internet connection required to install a GUI in Linux distros like CentOS 6.4 or Ubuntu Server from the terminal?

Comment: No, not if you have a CD/DVD/USB device containing all required packages.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays, most Linux distributions come with a GUI (e.g., Gnome, KDE, etc) already installed. The installation is done from the media (e.g., CD-ROM, DVD or USB pen) without Internet access. So, it is available as soon as you have installed your system.

This is the case, for example, of the so called "Desktop" distributions (e.g., Ubuntu, Mint, etc.). However, it depends on the particular distribution and each distribution is free to do as it wants.

Comment: So does centos live dvd 6.4 has gui pre installed or i need to install it?If yes then is internet required?

Comment: There are all the packages needed available on the DVD. Of course you need to install it. You actually need to install the OS using the Live DVD